# NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common

Tags: visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm having issues when I try to build the application that leads me to run a package restore, but that fails, and I can't update packages either.

```
NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.
Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 4.4.0 directly to project DACRL.Portal.Admin to resolve this issue. 

 DACRL.Portal.Admin -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils 7.0.1 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces (>= 4.4.0) 
 DACRL.Portal.Admin -> Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core 2022.3.1109 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 4.0.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces (= 4.0.0).
```

I have the latest SDK installed:

[image: dotnet --list-sdks]

And the whole solution (each project) is set to .net 7.0:

```xml
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
```

And the global.json is also setup correctly:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.101"
  }
}
```

The last thing that it advises is to manually install `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 4.4.0` directly to project `DACRL.Portal.Admin`, and that also fails.

```
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common.
Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 4.4.0 directly to project DACRL.Portal.Admin to resolve this issue. 

 DACRL.Portal.Admin -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 4.4.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.4.0) 
 DACRL.Portal.Admin -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.0 -> Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared 7.0.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features 4.0.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.0.0).
```

Comment: I have done the Delete Bin/Obj folder and cleaned up the temp dirs DotNet creates and also IIS-Express

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core 2022.3.1109` added v4.0.0 of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.*` DLLs. I had to manually add the following NuGtes:

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces

Now, solution compiles and NuGets get appropriately updated.